# Why is it true that $o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)=o(\vert t\vert)\cdot\Vert\vec u\Vert$?

Tags: limits

Why is it true that $o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)=o(\vert t\vert)\cdot\Vert\vec u\Vert$? As far as I can rewrite, we have:
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)}{\Vert t\vec u\Vert}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{\Vert\vec u\Vert}\cdot\frac{o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)}{\vert t\vert},
$$
so why don't we say $\begin{align}o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)=\frac{1}{\Vert\vec u\Vert} o(\vert t\vert)\end{align}$?

(I know it doesn't matter if we multiply by a constant $\Vert\vec u\Vert$, but I'm just confused why they multiply and don't divide by the constant. In the end it doesn't matter of course, because the constant disappears.)

I want to understand why my teacher wrote this:
[image]

Comment: If $u$ is fixed, then $o(\|tu\|) = o(|t|).$

Comment: More generally, if $u$ ranges among a family of vectors whose norms are bounded below and above by finite constants, then $o(\|tu\|) = o(|t|).$

Comment: @WillM. Yes, I understand that $o(\|tu\|) = o(|t|)$. However, my question was why my teacher wrote $o(\Vert t\vec u\Vert)=o(\vert t\vert)\cdot\Vert\vec u\Vert$. I added a screenshot of my teacher's lecture, so you can see where it's coming from. So I want to understand the reasoning of my teacher, even though it was redundant to add $\Vert\vec u\Vert$.

Comment: If $u$ is fixed, $\|u\| o(|t|) = o(|t|).$ Recall that $o(g)$ means that the function divided by $g$ converges to zero (in the highlighted point, usually zero).

Comment: $o(g)$ is an somewhat vague way of defining a limit implicitly.

Comment: @WillM. I'm afraid you don't seem to understand my question. I'm explicitly asking the reasoning behind writing $\Vert\vec u\Vert o(\vert t\vert)$. My teacher put it there for some reason. I see it's correct, but I don't understand why he put it there. Maybe I'll just mail him - that's probably the easiest solution!:)

Comment: @ShaVuklia What teacher wrote is an application of increment theorem.

Comment: @ShaVuklia I am affradid your teacher is using a shorthand notation for a limit and then trying to make it somewhat more formal, causing you to be confused about something cristal clear. Regardless, writting $o(|t|)$ is _**NOT**_ a function, is an expresion saying that whatever is equal to this expresion, it will go to zero faster that $|t|.$ Probably, he wanted to emphize that the implicit constatns depend on $\|u\|$ (or maybe, the implicit constant is exactly $\|u\|.$ Whatever, the point of using "little $o$" is to avoid writting the implicit constants).

Answer (score 0):

My last guess was right.

I will treat $o$ as a function (I shouldn't, because the point of $o$ is to express a limit; this is somewhat incorrect, but it seems what was done in lecture)

$f(a + tu) - f(a) = f'(a) tu + o(\|tu\|) = f'(a) tu + \left[\dfrac{o(|t|\|u\|)}{\|u\|}\right] \|u\|,$

the expression in square brackets is $o(|t|).$